# How do I check if input is blank/not blank and do specific thing

Tags: javascript, html, css

Okay so I know this is probably a headache for most of you but i'm having trouble figuring this out as javascript is not my strong suit.

I'm trying to basically get this one page to load if username and password is not blank but if it is blank I want it to alert to me (specifically window.alert()) that I have not inputted username and/or password.
I cannot seem to figure it out so here it is.

```
<button type="submit" id="enterButton" onclick="newPage()"><strong>Enter</strong></button>
```

there is my button where I put my function on

```
var username = getElementById("userName");
var password = getElementById("passWord");


    function newPage() {
        if(username.val().length==0 || password.val().length==0){
            alert("please enter valid information");
            return location.href = "newPage.html";
            }
            else{
                location.href = "newPage.html";
            }
        }
```

and here is my failed attempt to initialize my idea.

Comment: `.val()` is from jQuery, if you are using vanilla JS, you should be looking for `.value`. And, why setting location.href on if and also on else?

Comment: Your button is a type `submit`, as such you need to listen for the `onSubmit`, on the form tag.. eg -> https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ev_onsubmit

Answer (score 1):

```js
function validateform(){  
var name=document.myform.name.value;  
var password=document.myform.password.value;  
  
if (name==null || name==""){  
  alert("Name can't be blank");  
  return false;  
}else if (password==null || password==""){  
  alert("password can't be blank");  
  return false;  
} else if(password.length<6){  
  alert("Password must be at least 6 characters long.");  
  return false;  
  }  
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  
<body>  
<form name="myform" method="post" action="http://www.javatpoint.com/javascriptpages/valid.jsp" onsubmit="return validateform()" >  
Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br/>  
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br/>  
<input type="submit" value="register">  
</form>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should probably consider using trim here @AbuSaud. Because this way spaces would result in a valid input.

Comment: thanks @MihailMinkov  its just an example

Comment: @clover better check this too   https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_password_val

Answer (score 0):

Try to check first if you can get the value of your username. If you're using plain javascript, you should use `document.getElementById("userName").value`.